What is function of 'account required pam_faillock.so'?
I check pam configuration in /etc/pam.d/system-auth and /etc/pam.d/password-auth and I found line 'auth required pam_faillock.so'.
In some article that I read, if you want to set faillock you need line 'account required pam_faillock.so' instead of 'auth required pam_faillock.so'.
What happen if line 'account required pam_faillock.so' not set ??.
Pam configuration (/etc/pam.d/password-auth and /etc/pam.d/system-auth) using 'auth required pam_faillock.so' instead of 'account required pam_faillock.so', like configuration bellow :
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authselect is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faillock.so preauth silent
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
auth        required      pam_faillock.so authfail
auth        required      pam_deny.so

auth        required      pam_faillock.so
account     required      pam_unix.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so local_users_only enforce_for_root retry=3
password    requisite     pam_pwhistory.so enforce_for_root retry=3 remember=5
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow try_first_pass use_authtok remember=5
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so

This happen on a few server in my company.
I already test some deliberate failed login either using PAM configuration 'account required pam_faillock.so' or using PAM configuration 'auth required pam_faillock.so' in /etc/pam.d/password-auth and /etc/pam.d/system-auth, but I'm not found any difference result when I test deliberate failed login.
User that I tested still can be locked for a few minutes when some failed login happened.

The pam documentation discusses the difference between auth and account. Maybe that helps?
